# Serverless functions work locally but the deployed ones are unresponsive

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

We are changing things in our framework such as getting sequelize to work with serverless-bundle.

We tested all our new functions in this format:

```
serverless invoke local --function getObjects
```

It worked perfectly and remarkable fast.

Deployment went smoothly with no bugs, we had the debug flag set. The endpoints seem to work but the lambda functions are unresponsive.

Heres some of our serverless.yml

```
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  logs:
    restApi: true

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
       - "cloudwatch:*"

  functions:
    getObjects:
      handler: objects/get.main
      events:
        - http:
            path: objects
            method: get
            cors: true
            authorizer: aws_iam
```

The code seems identical to the bundle from local tests but it has a perpetual runtime, timing out no matter how large I make the lambda runtime in the console. Weirder still the lambda never throws an error and the logs effectively empty, suggesting it doesn't even initialize the function properly.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Interesting scenario, have you try to disable authorizer to see if it's the cause of it?
Also do you have any logs on cloudwatch from lambda or api gateway?

Comment: I just tried disabling the authorizers and it didn't help. We have logs set up, they seem to work but it only makes it to the first console.log which prints the received event input but then it doesn't print anything else. For instance, for the get call it only logs `INPUT {}` then eventually times out no matter how long we let it run for.

Comment: Even weirder if I pull the built bundle file from the lambda it's self into an editor I can run it locally with node but it still won't work in the lambda.

Comment: can you share the handler code that you executed on node?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that I had set an **inbound rule** in my **VPC Security Groups** that only allowed tcp connection for my ip-address. I changed it to **anywhere** and api started working remotely as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the VPC we were using in serverless was not authorized in our AWS security group for RDS. It never produced an error because it was waiting for the connection to the DB to time out and never rejected the request to the database because it was controlled by the IP. By adding the VPC to the security group it works just fine!